# Responsive design: How to adjust boxes according to container div when browser window gets resized

Tags: css, responsive-design

I would like to achieve that the boxes inside the container div resize and fit inside it when browser window is resized. At the moment container resizing works fine but I have problems with it's child elements. I've tried different ways but didn't get the desired result.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 21%;
  min-width: 262px;
  height: 202px;
  left: 47px;
  top: -164px;
  background-color: green;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #111111;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 5px;
}

#box_inside_1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 16%;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -36px;
  left: 29px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #111111;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#box_inside_2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 16%;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -105px;
  left: 260px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #111111;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#box_inside_3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 16%;
  min-width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: -172px;
  left: 515px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #111111;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div id="box_inside_1"></div>
   <div id="box_inside_2"></div>
   <div id="box_inside_3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is HTML code?

Comment: @SVK sorry, I just updated my question

Comment: Expectation is not clear so its better, if you'll sketch something or elaborate more about your result.

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container should probably be the thing that has an id, and the boxes should have a class.  For instance, if you want to have 3 inline divs within the container, you could do this:

```
<style>
    #container {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .box-inside {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 16%;
        height: 50px;
    }
</style>
<div id='container'>
    <div class='box-inside'>
    </div>
    <div class='box-inside'>
    </div>
    <div class='box-inside'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or, alternatively, you could make the inner divs display block and float: left or float: right and then put

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

after them to clear the floating functionality.  Or, if you do not want them inline, then just make them display: block, and they will fall one after the other.  What you probably do not want though, is absolute positioning, because you appear to have a list of very similar divs.  Absolute positioning is more appropriate for niche cases of weird layouts.  Also, the top, left, right, and bottom styles only apply when the position is absolute, fixed, or relative, so you don't need those if you use the default static positioning on the inner boxes.

Comment: it works! I need to add some top & margin values, but It works, thanks!!!